# Calculating geometry for feature class with x/y and Lat/Long values in different projections?

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, latitude-longitude, xy

I have a feature class with x/y values populated on the native projection of the feature class (state plane).

In the same feature class I also have Lat/Long fields that I need to populate (WGS 84 in decimal degree).

The problem I have is the calculate geometry function doesn't allow me to choose a different projection other than State Plane when I try to auto populate the Lat/Long values.

Does anyone have any python code or ideas that might help with this request?

Comment: Add the data to ArcMap, set the data frame to WGS 84 (set a geographic transformation if needed!). Now try calculate geometry.

Comment: Also asked on [GeoNet](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/164114)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you just need to run a cursor on it and use the `projectAs()` geometry method.

```
import arcpy

fc = r'C:\path_to\your_data\points.shp'

wgs = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ['SHAPE@', 'lat_field', 'long_field']) as rows:
    for row in rows:
        pnt_wgs = row[0].projectAs(wgs)
        row[1:] = [pnt_wgs.centroid.Y, pnt_wgs.centroid.X] #will be in decimal degrees
        rows.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help cmackey...when I run that code I get an error as follows.....AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'spatialReference'.....any ideas on that?

Comment: Looks like you need to capitalize the `S` in `SpatialReference`.  Python is a case sensitive language.

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to ArcMap 10.2.1+, you can use [Add Geometry Attributes](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-geometry-attributes.htm), which allows you to specify a coordinate system.

```
spatref = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326) #WGS 84    
arcpy.AddGeometryAttributes_management(FC, "POINT_X_Y_Z_M", "FEET_US", "ACRES", spatref)
```

It's a script, not a tool, which means that you can inspect the code behind it to see what it does. It's similar to the answer posted by @crmackey, though it utilizes the `spatial_reference` parameter of `UpdateCursor`.